# Emberjs - Custom Adapter

Tags: ember.js

I'm quit new into the world of the Adapter in Ember, and I would like to create a custom one to save some data into the webSQL database for the compatible browser.

It might look very simple but I'm stuck at the beginning of this process.

I have this in a separate file :

```
DS.WebSQLAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
    dbName: 'testDb',
    dbVersion: '1.0',
    dbDisplayName: 'Test Db',
    dbSize: (2 * 1024 * 1024),

    init: function() {
        this.db = cont.openDatabase( this.dbName, this.dbVersion, this.dbDisplayName, this.dbSize );
    },
    createRecord: function( store, type, query, recordArray ) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

In my app.js file :

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.WebSQLAdapter;
```

And when I do this in my controller :

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    actions: {
        myAction: function() {
            this.store.createRecord('someDB', {key: 'test', title: 'myTitle'});
        }
    }
})
```

It says that it couldn't found the model `someDB`.. Do I need to create a model as well for my adapter even though I'm using websql to fetch the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that `SomeDB` doesn't exist. Ember is expecting the following to be in your code somewhere:

```
App.SomeDB = DS.Model.extend({});
```

If you don't declare a `SomeDB` model, you can't create a new record of that type. (At least not with the Ember-Data store.)

Comment: Great, it's kinda working now. But when I use createRecord, it doesn't seems to use my adapter.. but its using the store correctly.

Comment: `createRecord()` only creates a client side record, so it won't touch the adapter. You have to call `save()` on the record for it to persist to the server and use the adapter.